# Android Dev: High noise floor on audio recordings on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, audio-recording, samsung-mobile, noise-reduction

I am building an app to analyze voice quality.The user makes a voice recording which is stored on the device and then sent to a server for analysis.

I recently noticed that all audio recordings from **Samsung Galaxy S6 (G920-F)** are much noisier than other tested Android devices. I need to support the Galaxy S6 as I have many users on this phone.

I an attempt to fix the issue I tried testing **MediaRecorder** with different Audiosources such as: DEFAULT, MIC, VOICE_RECOGNITION and VOICE_COMMUNICATION. None of these options have a significant impact on noise.

I then tested using **AudioRecorder** with the same AudioSources listed above. No improvement.

Finally I tried adding a **NoiseSuppressor** to AudioRecorder which showed very little to no improvement.

*I am setting up the AudioRecorder and NoiseSuppressor as follows:*

```
public void startRecording(String fileNameIn) {
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize (
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
        aRecorder = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                bufferSize);

        int audioSession = aRecorder.getAudioSessionId();
        enableNoiseSuppressor(audioSession);


        aRecorder.startRecording();
        ......
```

and

```
public void enableNoiseSuppressor(int microphoneId) {
        if (NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable() && noiseSuppressor == null) {
            noiseSuppressor = NoiseSuppressor.create(microphoneId);
            noiseSuppressor.setEnabled(true);
            Log.i(TAG, "NoiseSuppressor enabled");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "This device don't support NoiseSuppressor");
        }
    }
```

I also tested 3rd party recording apps on the **Galaxy S6** and notice a high noise level on these recordings as well. This seems like a strange problem to have from a flagship (a few years back) phone. Are there any Android tricks or core concepts I am missing?

Looking for any suggestions or advice.